# How to setup GitHub repo so that certain team members can't write to master branch

Tags: github

Newbie GitHub question: I have setup an **organization** in GitHub and created a **private** repository.  Now, how do I only allow only certain members the ability to push to the master branch, while allowing others the ability to create & push branches other than master?

Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?  I basically want to have a review process so that code must be reviewed before being merged into master and don't want to let contributors just be able to push directly to master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best will be to restrict writing to your main repo (where master live) to your allowed developper. And you give read access to the other; this way they can `fork` the repo (forks will remain private).

Then, when they want to merge with Master they send a pull request.

If unauthorized developpers need to share branches between them, they can then add each other forks as remote and pull/pull request as any other repo.

Hope this help!